# Serializing a serializable object passed over as Object

Tags: java, object, serialization, casting, serializable

So I have a class called Person that implements Serializable.

When I pass over an instance of Person to a method called "saveToFile(Object obj)", then I do

```
class FileManager() implements IGateway{
    public void saveToFile(Object ms) throws IOException {
        OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(PATH);
        OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);

        // serialize
        output.writeObject((Person)ms); //cast to serializable class
        output.close();
    }
}
```

```
public class Person implements Serializable{
    private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<Message>>> messageBoxes;
    private IGateway iGateway;

    public Person(){
        iGateway = new MessageManager();
        messageBoxes = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<Message>>>();
    }

    public void saveMessage(){
        iGateway.saveToFile(this);
    }
}
```

```
public interface IGateway {
    void saveToFile(Object obj) throws IOException;
}
```

which gives me NotSerializableException. I need to keep receiving the Person instances as Object for design reasons. Why would it keep giving NotSerializableException when I'm casting it to serializable class?

Comment: What does the `Person` class look like? Can you paste it here?

Answer (score 0):

The fields in the `Person` class have their own types that can be not `Serializable`.

For example here:

1. Your `HashMap` field implements a default `Serializable` interface, this is ok.
2. The field named `iGateway` has a type of `IGateway` which is **not serializable** by default.

You have to either use a third-party library for serialization which can handle such things, or make it serializable as well.

You can also override the `writeObject` for the `Person` class with your custom code, but make sure you do not try to serialize other objects that do not implement this interface.